# How to set standard C++ 2003 in CMake

Tags: cmake, c++03

I'm looking for solution how to set standard of C++ to 2003 in cmake. I can find a lot of information how to do it on later versions like 11, 17 and so on. But for 2003 version I couldn't find it. Does someone knows how to set it? I found also how to do it by adding flag to every cmake list that project contains. The problem is that I have a lot of cmake lists in my project and I want to add it once in main cmake lists.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

See the docs for [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD)

> Supported values are: [98, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23].

`03` is not supported.

---

Notes:

Note that while gcc supports `-std=c++03` as a flag, it is [just an alias for `-std=c++98`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/c-family/c.opt#L2073). So the two flags have the same effect and it [doesn't make a difference which of the two you use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html):

> The original ISO C++ standard was published as the ISO standard (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) and amended by a Technical Corrigenda published in 2003 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003). These standards are referred to as C++98 and C++03, respectively. GCC implements the majority of C++98 (export is a notable exception) and most of the changes in C++03. To select this standard in GCC, use one of the options -ansi, -std=c++98, or -std=c++03; to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be errors rather than warnings).

MSVC [does not provide flags for selecting standards older than C++14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category) (ctrl+F for "/std").